# eclipse debugger points to false line in the source code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven

I use exlipse kepler with m2e. When debugging a maven project with the debugger, it shows me the false line numbers in the debugger. It starts at the javadoc and does not enter into the function body.

I read in google that there may be problems with eclipse juno but not with kepler.

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Is the code that you are stepping thru in a jar file?

Comment: Almost 100% of the times, this is because your code is out-of-sync. Try rebuild the project and see if that helps.

Comment: it is a maven dependency. I have jar and source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check that the jar/war that is deployed is in sync with the code in your eclipse workspace. Maybe you edited some code after deployment?

If that is not the problem, you can also check that the correct source is attached to the Debug Configuration (Source tab).

Comment: I used the brute force approach. I deleted the maven dependency and updated the project. This helped.